# Where is coverage.xml located in Codecov?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, code-coverage, codecov

I use `/home/runner/work/SIESTAstepper/SIESTAstepper/coverage.xml` but I think the path is not correct. My report is not uploading on GitHub Actions.

[Full file](https://github.com/eftalgezer/SIESTAstepper/blob/main/.github/workflows/python-package.yml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coverage file is located at `/home/runner/work/SIESTAstepper/SIESTAstepper/coverage.xml`. In general, it is `/home/runner/work/<project>/<project>/coverage.xml`.

I solved it with the following code.

```
    - name: Generate Report
      run: |
        pip install codecov
        pip install pytest-cov
        pytest --cov=./ --cov-report=xml
        codecov
    - name: Upload coverage to Codecov
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v3.1.0
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
        directory: ./coverage/reports/
        env_vars: OS,PYTHON
        files: /home/runner/work/SIESTAstepper/SIESTAstepper/coverage.xml
        flags: tests
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/eftalgezer/SIESTAstepper/blob/main/.github/workflows/python-package.yml).

Comment: Good feedback. Upvoted. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

From your [last run](https://github.com/eftalgezer/SIESTAstepper/actions/runs/3079334536/jobs/4975501501#step:6:205), check if the "Upload coverage to CodeCov" is actually executed.

The workflow seems to stop *before* that, in the `test with pytest` step:

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.13/x64/lib/python3.7/distutils/file_util.py:44: DistutilsFileError
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED tests/__main__.py::test_merge_ani - distutils.errors.DistutilsFileErro...
FAILED tests/tests.py::test_merge_ani - distutils.errors.DistutilsFileError: ...
========================= 2 failed, 30 passed in 4.23s =========================
```

If it does not stop before that, you need to check if the file is indeed created, considering the [error message](https://github.com/eftalgezer/SIESTAstepper/actions/runs/3081602423/jobs/4980339719) is:

```
 None of the following appear to exist as files: ./coverage.xml
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. The test fails. But the tests which do not fail do not upload the coverage report. 

https://github.com/eftalgezer/SIESTAstepper/actions/runs/3077712442/jobs/4972763464

Comment: This is the latest run: https://github.com/eftalgezer/SIESTAstepper/actions/runs/3081602423/jobs/4980339719

Comment: @EftalGezer "None of the following appear to exist as files: ./coverage.xml": Can you add steps to do a `pwd`, `ls -alrth`, and a `cat ./coverage.xml`? That way we will know if the file were there (and where ('there' is)

Comment: The coverage report was not created. I have solved it, it works now. I am adding it as an answer.